# ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, indexoutofboundsexception, google-tasks

I am trying to sync google tasks with my application. For this I have created a class in which I have created all the methods which needs to get task lists and create the list etc.

Now I want to test If these methods are working or not. For this I have created a class which extends an `AsyncTask`.

I have to pass some parameters in this task as in methods I have parameters. Like in `getTaskList(Strig listId)`. To get tasks from any list I will need to provide an id of a list.

Now when I tried to pass parameters in AsyncTask. While calling it in

```
result = gTaskSyncer.getTaskList(params[0].toString());
```

its throwing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` here.

TestAsyncTask

```
 public class TestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object,Void,List<Task>>{

    private com.google.api.services.tasks.Tasks mService = null;
    private Exception mLastError = null;
    private MainActivity activity;
    private com.google.api.services.tasks.Tasks client = null;

    public TestAsyncTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential, MainActivity activity) {
        HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        mService = new com.google.api.services.tasks.Tasks.Builder(
                transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("Google Tasks API Android Quickstart")
                .build();
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    protected List<Task> doInBackground(Object... params) {



        GTaskSyncer gTaskSyncer = new GTaskSyncer(activity);

        List<Task> result = new ArrayList<>();

        try {

            result = gTaskSyncer.getTaskList(params[0].toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {

            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "No tasks.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Task> output) {
        activity.mProgress.hide();
        if (output == null || output.size() == 0) {
            activity.mOutputText.setText("No results returned.");
        } else {
            activity.mOutputText.setText(TextUtils.join("\n", output));
        }
    }
}
```

GTaskSyncer

```
 public class GTaskSyncer
{

    final MainActivity activity;
    final com.google.api.services.tasks.Tasks mService;
    private Exception mLastError = null;



    GTaskSyncer(MainActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        mService = activity.mService;
    }

    public List<TaskList> getAllTaskList() throws IOException
    {
        List<TaskList> result = new ArrayList<TaskList>();

        TaskLists taskLists = mService.tasklists().list().execute();

        for (TaskList taskList : taskLists.getItems()) {

                result.add(taskList);
        }

        return result;

    }


    public TaskList createList() throws IOException
    {

        TaskList taskList = new TaskList();

        taskList =  activity.mService.tasklists().insert(taskList).execute();

        return taskList;
    }

    public Task createTask(String listId) throws IOException
    {

        Task task = new Task();

        task =   activity.mService.tasks().insert(listId, task).execute();

        return  task;
    }

    public Task getTask(String listId,String taskId) throws IOException
    {

        Task task =   activity.mService.tasks().get(listId, taskId).execute();

        return task;
    }

    public List<Task> getTaskList(String listId) throws IOException {


        List<Task> result = new ArrayList<Task>();

        List<Task> tasks = mService.tasks().list(listId).execute().getItems();

        if (tasks != null) {

            for (Task task : tasks) {

                result.add(task);
            }
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(activity, "No tasks.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return result;

    }

}
```

Also how can I test this? How to provide a listId to method when we call it?

Comment: I guess the result you are returning is an empty list, so array index out of bound error size zero and index 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> An array  out of bounds exception is a Java exception thrown due to
>   the fact that the program is trying to access an element at a position
>   that is outside an array limit, hence the words "Out of bounds".

**Problem**

```
 result = gTaskSyncer.getTaskList(params[0].toString()); // In here Problem
```

> Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal
>   index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the
>   size of the array.

- I assume in your `doInBackground` section **result** is  illegal index .

Comment: which value i should add to test? I wantt all tasks from some list. How can I pass the listId here? @IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: at first check values of `params[0].toString()`

Comment: how? @ IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: sorry m a beginner I don't know how to do. Can you please show me through code.@IntelliJ Amiya

Answer (score 2):

When you call execute() on an `AsyncTask` without any arguments, that missing argument to execute() becomes an empty (varargs) array in the **AsyncTask's** `doInBackground()` method.

If you want to be able to use parameters in `doInBackground()`, then you must pass some parameters via `execute()`.  If you want to make sure you don't index past the list of items passed in execute, iterate the vararg arg array instead of indexing directly into it without checking its length.

Comment: yes that's right. But what should I pass in execute to test the method? I want to get all tasks from particular list. I want to pass a listId. How can  I? @Doug Stevenson

Comment: You don't have to pass anything if you don't want to.  Or maybe you just pass the necessary list to the AsyncTask. It's up to you, but the caller and task have to agree on what is being passed and how to use it.

Comment: I want to pass listId. to get tasks of the same list. How can I

Answer (score 0):

First check that, you are passing a value when you are calling the Asynctask class . `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` occurs because you are not passing but want to access that.

So, before access that parameter first check that if the size is greater than 1.